# windows7 stop at "starting windows" while intalling on kvm

Tags: windows-7, centos7, qemu, kvm, libvirt

After updating my KVM to a newer version,I cannot install windows7 anymore.

Following is the command to install:

```
virt-install --name win7 --memory 8192 --vcpu sockets=1,cores=8,threads=1 \
--cdrom=/usr/local/kvm/iso/win7.iso \
--disk path=/usr/local/kvm/images/win7.img,size=100,bus=sata \
--network bridge=br0,model=virtio \
--os-type windows --os-variant win7 \
--noautoconsole --accelerate --hvm \
--graphics vnc,password=123456,listen=0.0.0.0,port=20001 \
--cpu host-passthrough --arch x86_64
```

I'm sure it worked earlier with the same command until I updated my server two days ago.

It is stuck here:
[Click here to see pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C91F0.jpg)

some version Information:

```
centos7 3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64
libvirt 1.2.17
```

I tried to install windows10 and it's working properly.

Does anyone know about this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

solved!

Look here:[Windows 7 Setup hangs at “Starting Windows” using Proxmox 4.2](https://serverfault.com/questions/776406/windows-7-setup-hangs-at-starting-windows-using-proxmox-4-2)

and add this to command line:

```
--video cirrus
```

Answer (score 1):

Machine Detail -> Video -> selected cirrus

Comment: unfortunately
I do not have a GUI